# I'm creating a patrolling AI that aggros to the player and follows them in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

I'm having trouble keeping this method running. It runs for 1 frame them shuts itself off. I am having trouble working out the logic to keep it running. Yes, the enemy does detect if the player is within a field of view, and it does stop when it collides with walls, it also stops detecting the player when they leave the fov.

I've tried changing around if statements, but it's overall very important that the code runs based on the player existing in the FOV collider. The problem is pretty specific, so I don't know what research to do.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(NavMeshAgent))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float patrolSpeed, chaseSpeed, chaseWaitTime, patrolWaitTime, castRadius;
    public Transform[] wayPoints, wayPOI;
    public Transform player;
    public Animation flinch, die;
    public AudioClip grunt, callOut, death;
    public LayerMask mask;
    public PlayerCheck check;
    private float chaseTimer, patrolTimer, wanderTimer;
    private int destIndex, destInit, destStart, health;
    private bool playerIn;
    protected string aggro, resting, warned, sawPlayer;
    protected bool patroling;
    public bool aggress;
    private NavMeshAgent agent;
    private Transform playerLP;
    private Vector3 startPos;
    private Animator anim;
    private AudioSource aud;
    MeshCollider fieldOfView;
    void Awake()
    {
        //patroling = true;
        startPos = transform.position;
        destInit = destIndex;
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        agent.autoRepath = true;
        agent.autoBraking = true;
        fieldOfView = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
        if (fieldOfView == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("The first object MUST be FOV, otherwise the script will not work correctly. 1");
        }
        check = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<PlayerCheck>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (check == null)
        {
            check = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<PlayerCheck>();
        }

        playerIn = check.playerIn;
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Linecast(transform.position, player.position, out hit, ~mask))
        {
            if (!playerIn)
            {
                Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hit.point, Color.red);
            }
            else if (hit.collider.gameObject != null)
            {
                if (!hit.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
                {
                    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hit.point, Color.blue);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hit.point, Color.green);
                    aggress = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (aggress)
        {
            Aggro(sawPlayer);
        }

        if (patroling)
        {
            GoToNext();
        }
    }

    void GoToNext()
    {
        patroling = true;
        aggress = false;
        if (wayPoints.Length == 0)
            return;

        if (playerIn)
            return;

        if (agent.remainingDistance < .7f)
        {
            agent.SetDestination(wayPoints[destIndex].position);
            destIndex = (destIndex + 1) % wayPoints.Length;
        }
    }

    void Aggro(string condition)
    {
        if (condition == sawPlayer)
        {
            Chase(player);
        }
    }

    void Chase(Transform transform)
    {
        patroling = false;
        if (playerIn)
        {
            agent.SetDestination(transform.position);
            print("Chasing");
        }
        else
        {
            **Wander(sawPlayer, 15);**
            print("Wander, please");
        }
    }

    **void Wander(string condition, float time)**
    {
        patroling = false;
        print(time);
        wanderTimer += Time.deltaTime;

        print("Wandering");
        //this is where I'm having the most trouble, it will print wandering for 1 //frame then stop and go back to patroling
        //once the player leaves the fov. I'm trying to figure out where the method //stops and why.

        if (condition == sawPlayer)
        {
            if (wanderTimer >= time)
            {
                wanderTimer = 0;
                if (!agent.pathPending && agent.remainingDistance < .5f)
                {
                    GoToNext();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Vector3 vec;
                vec = new Vector3(Random.Range(agent.destination.x - 10, agent.destination.x), Random.Range(agent.destination.y - 10, agent.destination.y), Random.Range(agent.destination.z - 10, agent.destination.z));
                agent.destination = transform.InverseTransformDirection(vec);

                if (agent.remainingDistance < .3f || wanderTimer > time)
                {
                    GoToNext();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have lost the whitespace in your code.....you should also think about making a minimal example, your actual question seems to have nothing to do with AI, and the title doesn't reflect your actual question

Comment: Some advice, this script is pretty massive, a lot of the things in this script should be able to be moved and refactor into other components.  Also think about highlighting exactly which method is having the problem, your script has a few methods in it.

Comment: Alright, also sorry I've never used Stack Overflow before, so I'll try, but for now the method that's having the issue is Wander(). The specific issue I'm having is that the method runs only while the player is in the field of view.

Comment: If you dont want it to stop when fov stops, have an "ischasing" flag, and if ischasing and the distance to the player is < "n" then keep chasing